# Are there any triggers for file imports done using browser?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I was under the assumption that the `afterSave()` or `beforeSave()` triggers will fire for every new row (object) created when I import a CSV file using the browser. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case.

So, are there any triggers available for processing newly created objects (rows) when importing files via browser?

Edit: I'm calling beforeSave() in my Cloud Code as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Transaction", function(request) {
    // code here
});
```

When I import a CSV file into my Transcation class, the beforeSave does not trigger. However, if I add a new row using the browser, then it does fire as expected.

Comment: Could you show the context in which these functions are used in your program?

Comment: I was sure I read somewhere that this worked, but it doesn't for me either. Given that parse docs often suggest de-normalising data to overcome their lack of various query support it's very frustrating not to be able to use your automatic denormalisation functions

Comment: see also: https://parse.com/questions/importing-data-and-cloud-aftersave-code